# Alea GPU - Passing structures of arrays

Tags: aleagpu

I have a simple question. Is it possible to write structures of arrays like this with Alea.Gpu?

```
        public struct SVDFactorsStructGpu
        {
            public deviceptr<float> ItemsBiases;
            public deviceptr<float> UsersBiases;
            public deviceptr<float> ItemsFeatures;
            public deviceptr<float> UsersFeatures;
        }
[...]
        SVDFactorsStructGpu factors = new SVDFactorsStructGpu();
        factors.ItemsBiases = gpuItemsBiases.Ptr;
        factors.UsersBiases = gpuUsersBiases.Ptr;
        factors.ItemsFeatures = gpuItemsFeatures.Ptr;
        factors.UsersFeatures = gpuUsersFeatures.Ptr;
[...]
```

And pass them somehow like this to a kernel:

```
    public void TrainEpochKernel(SVDParamsStructGpu svdParams,
                                 deviceptr<float> ratings,
                                 deviceptr<int> ratingsItemsIds,
                                 deviceptr<int> userProfilesIds,
                                 deviceptr<int> ratingsStartIdxs,
                                 deviceptr<int> ratingsCounts,
                                 deviceptr<float> userProfilesSSE,
                                 SVDFactorsStructGpu factors)
    {
        int startUserProfileIdx = blockIdx.x * (blockDim.x * svdParams.StridePerThread) + threadIdx.x * svdParams.StridePerThread;

[...]
                pred = svdParams.GlobalMean;
                pred += factors.ItemsBiases[i];
                pred += factors.UsersBiases[u];
[...]
```

This works without a structure but yields an illegal address when encapsulated.

Thanks in advance

[edit #1] It seems that the Ptr copy is in cause here, as if I try to pass them from the structure directly in the kernel signature the error is the same.

[edit #2] Maybe it is a very obvious question, I tried to pass the DeviceMemory<> directly but was unable to set values. I am going to keep the "one parameter for one array version" as it is not critical and got a very efficient algorithm overall. Was just curious to know more about Alea.Gpu C#.

Comment: For information, QuantAlea GPU was used in the following article: 

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-batch-hpc-learning-20-million-ratings-seconds-c%C3%A9dric-dell%C3%A9a

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cf, comment above. Everything worked fine with the arrays. :)